# Extracting sublists

Tags: python, python-2.7, append, sublist

What is happening on this line in the following code: `d.append(b[-1] + 1)`?

```
d= [2, 4, 6, 8, 12]
b[0] = -1 
d.append(b[-1] + 1)
print d
```

Comment: What is `b` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `b` is a list of integers, the code takes the last element from the list `b`, adds one to it, and then appends the value to list `d`.